# Rootless mode: My docker container has internet but can not ping

Tags: docker

I just noticed that my docker container has internet connection. Because I can update or download packages. But I can not ping google. I do not think it is a DNS issue. Because I can not ping 8.8.8.8 either.

```
% docker run -it --name alpine5 alpine ash
/ # apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.15.0-172-g86e4642bdd [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main]
v3.15.0-173-g0bd3b989ee [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community]
OK: 15837 distinct packages available
/ # apk add openssh
(1/10) Installing openssh-keygen (8.8_p1-r1)
(2/10) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.3_p20211120-r0)
(3/10) Installing ncurses-libs (6.3_p20211120-r0)
(4/10) Installing libedit (20210910.3.1-r0)
(5/10) Installing openssh-client-common (8.8_p1-r1)
(6/10) Installing openssh-client-default (8.8_p1-r1)
(7/10) Installing openssh-sftp-server (8.8_p1-r1)
(8/10) Installing openssh-server-common (8.8_p1-r1)
(9/10) Installing openssh-server (8.8_p1-r1)
(10/10) Installing openssh (8.8_p1-r1)
Executing busybox-1.34.1-r3.trigger
OK: 12 MiB in 24 packages
/ # ping -c 2 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.160.142): 56 data bytes

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/ # ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

What might be the issue here?

**Update 1**

I wanted to add that in my host machine (Linux Mint 20.2) the interfaces are:

```
% ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:31:bf:b5:e6:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In the container, the interface are:

```
$ docker container attach alpine5
/ # ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
61: eth0@if62: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.7/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
/ # ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
61: eth0@if62: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

There is no `docker0` interface. One more thing I need to mention is , I am using docker in rootless mode.

Comment: @emix it seems to be a known issue of rootless mode. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#routing-ping-packets . However, the workaround which is to "Add `net.ipv4.ping_group_range = 0 2147483647` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run `sudo sysctl --system`" is also not working for me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240704/discussion-on-question-by-blueray-rootless-mode-my-docker-container-has-interne).

Comment: @deceze Can the comments or that chat be revived? I have the exact issue and the (probably very useful) conversation has been lost.

Comment: @rinu There really wasn't a lot of useful content there.